# statistical software JASP and its credibility for academic reasearch

Tags: references, jasp

I have been using JASP sw for a month or so, and I like it. But what's been bothering me is that my professor in uni doesn't know this sw and is doubting its credibility.

I would appreciate suggestions for scholarly literature testing its credibility.

Comment: Asking what we *think* of JASP is an opinion-based question and off-topic. But asking for *references* on JASP is on-topic. I took the liberty of adding the [tag:references] tag. Do you want to edit your question to clarify?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: The question must have been improved. At least it does not ask us of what we think. I think it is a relevant question that should be opened again.

Answer (score 1):

[JASP](https://jasp-stats.org/) is actively developed by employees and students of the University of Amsterdam and the open-source community. It uses R and Stan as its workhorse. On its page, JASP lists its advisory board consisting of lecturers from the University of Amsterdam and other universities and provides some references describing it. So I’d send your professor the link to the JASP page.

Comment: There is also a full on verification / replication project that checks if JASP gives the same results as others: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615395/statistical-software-jasp-and-its-credibility-for-academic-reasearch
See also: https://jasp-stats.org/2021/02/03/the-jasp-verification-project/
JASP also just uses lots of R packages. It is a bit ignorant to doubt its credibility.